# How can I replicate the flavor of Mountain Dew?

Tags: flavor, soda

[Mountain Dew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mountain_Dew) is often described as 'citrus' flavor but that is a broad range of fruits with infinite possible combinations. It does have orange juice [in the ingredients](http://www.pepsicobeveragefacts.com/Home/Product?formula=44316%2A01%2A01-07&form=RTD&size=20), but also "natural flavor". How can I recreate the flavor of Mountain Dew using ingredients available to me, such as fruit juices, with no added sugar or caffeine?

Comment: To me Sprite and Sierra Mist taste like citrus. I have never associated Mountain Dew with citrus.

Comment: I've heard grapefruit, but when I think 'grapefruit soda', I think Fresca.

Comment: It's been some time since i've last had mountain dew.... IIRC there was a slight artificial vanilla taste, similar to most colas?

Comment: I think that the only way to answer this definitively is if Mountain Dew sells a version of their drink somewhere where labelling laws require them to explicitly list all the flavours included; all the current answers are just speculation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, this is dangerously close to a recipe request, but far enough away that I feel OK to answer.

Use the rule of two.

- 2 cups of sugar
- 2 two oranges
- 2 limes
- 2 lemons

Juice and zest the whole fruit.

Strain and and fill to 1 gallon with water. Filter if you want it to be clear.

Carbonate using whatever technique you normally use whether that's a Cornelius keg or soda stream.

Comment: 1. Thanks for your response. 
2. Just because you answered with a recipe doesn't mean I asked for one :) (equal amounts of orange, lemon and lime + zest, sweeten to taste would have been a 'fair' answer)

Comment: 'restaurant mimicry' is specifically allowed, though ... which this is closer to.

Comment: No way you are going to carbonate that in a soda stream without foaming all over the place.

Comment: Actually, if you are just patient with a Soda Stream and let it sit for a few minutes after charging it you don't get the eruption.

Comment: Yep, we use the soda stream also. Some syrups erupt, others don't and as @CosCallis has said, sometimes it's just oatience in letting the co2 settle into suspension, sometimes it's pouring in the syrup at s trickle to avoid the mentos volcano.

Answer (score 2):

I definitely taste Grapefruit, but I suspect there is a bit of Mango as well as the Lime and Lemon. I think the Mango might be what adds a bit of the candy like flavor to it (asides from the sugar).

Answer (score -3):

I drink Diet Dew daily am to pm. At times I sensed one of the complexity of 3-4 citrus flavors is a hint of grapefruit.